# Has anybody seen a template for a stacked bar chart race...?

Tags: flourishlib

I’m in need a flourish template for doing a stacked bar chart race.  Any suggestions.?

I
Have searched the forums and haven’t been successful.  As another possible approach, is it possible to modify an existing template?

Comment: wow. I have the exact same requirement. e.g. a Stacked bar chart of Target Revenue vs. Actual Revenue - compared across business lines.